# Adding a complicated launcher to the "Open With" list in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, ubuntu-12.04, command-line-arguments, launcher

I have a complicated shortcut/launcher that I would like to put in the Open With list. The shortcut uses the command

```
screen -d -m bash -c "screen;source /home/me/intel/bin/compilervars.sh intel64;/home/me/QtCreator/QtCreator2.8.1-gcc/bin/qtcreator"
```

Where it's that complicated because it has to execute a script for the intel compiler. I have tried to change the command to

```
screen -d -m bash -c "screen;source /home/me/intel/bin/compilervars.sh intel64;/home/me/QtCreator/QtCreator2.8.1-gcc/bin/qtcreator %F"
```

and then copy the QtCreator.desktop file to /use/share/applications/ but it didn't work.

What should I do? I read many tutorials on this, but I think I have a special case with this weird launcher command.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution

The value of the `Exec` line in your Desktop Entry should look like this:

```
screen -d -m bash -c "screen;source /home/me/intel/bin/compilervars.sh intel64;/home/me/QtCreator/QtCreator2.8.1-gcc/bin/qtcreator \"\$@\"" dummy %F
```

BTW: why do you have `screen;` at the beginning of your bash command string? If I’m not mistaken, that shouldn’t be necessary.

I should also mention that I have successfully tested this with the following `Exec` command because I don’t have QtCreator here:

```
screen -d -m bash -c "libreoffice --writer \"\$@\"" dummy %F
```

### Explanation

Because of the many “layers” that are involved here, it is a bit tricky to

1. correctly pass the arguments from the launcher down to QtCreator.
2. get the quoting right.

Let’s start with the first problem: You can’t use `%F` within an argument (i.e., within quotes) in the `Exec` command of a launcher, see [the last line of this spec page](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/ar01s06.html) which says:

> The %F and %U field codes may only be used as an argument on their own.

So you are bound to have the launcher arguments (i.e., `%F`) as arguments on the outmost “layer”. But you want to get them into the little bash command. Luckily, bash uses all arguments after the first argument to its `-c` option as positional parameters. Unfortunately, bash starts to number them from 0, i.e., it uses `$0`, `$1`, `$2`, etc. So you can’t just access them all with `$@` inside the script because you would miss the first (`$0`) argument then. That’s why I have added the `dummy` argument: it is always assigned to `$0` which is never used in our case. All real arguments (i.e., `%F`) are completely passed into `$@`.

Great, we have solved the first problem: we have managed to get all our command line arguments from the launcher into the little bash command.

Now to the problem of quoting. The double quotes around the bash command are interpreted by the launcher. Everything between these quotes consequently has to adhere to [the Desktop Entry specification](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/ar01s06.html). In a plain bash script, the (shortened) call would look like this:

```
qtcreator "$@"
```

Because each argument can contain spaces, we have to quote the `$@` variable. Now the `Exec` key specification demands that (amongst others), double quotes and dollar signs need to be quoted if they are used within double quotes – which is what we do. Second problem solved, too.

Comment: You're the best :)